# Security audit - AU-8 Time Stamps

Tags: auditing

I'm making a security audit to a Sharepoint farm and have a question about this control:

**"AU-8 Time Stamps The system must use internal system clocks to generate time stamps for audit records."**

do you know if it is related to the audit of Sharepoint or related to the windows server?

Comment: Like Trevor said it is a Operating system level, I've found this example:

7.5 TIME STAMPS Instructions:  Describe how the Company’s information system will provide time stamps for use in audit record generation. 

Clock / calendar settings for the main server, the alarm system, and the video surveillance system shall be checked and adjusted approximately once every six months, at the changeovers to their local time zone (EST, CST, PST and so on…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [AU-8](https://www.stigviewer.com/controls/800-53/AU-8), this appears to be at the Operating System level. SharePoint uses the Operating System clock to create entries.